# Множество ошибок при запуске бота

Tags: node.js, бот

Бота я пишу на node JS. Он предназначен для Дискорда.

Я решил залить весь код:

https://yadi.sk/d/KBqynLnoxoiO2w

Суть в том, что когда я пишу команду "ping", бот должен мне ответить "pong".

Вот сами логи:

```
(node:10496) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bot' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\miste\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\ShiroBot\ShiroBot.js:28:31)      
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\miste\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\ShiroBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\miste\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\ShiroBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\miste\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\ShiroBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\miste\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\ShiroBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\miste\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\ShiroBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\miste\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\ShiroBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\miste\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\ShiroBot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:800:20)
(node:10496) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10496) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: В приведенных фрагментах кода нет строки, которая могла бы привести к такой ошибке.

Comment: @Yaant Вот весь код. Если будет время буду рад помощи. https://yadi.sk/d/KBqynLnoxoiO2w

Comment: Ошибка указывает на 28 строку. Смотрим на нее и видим: `if(Discord.Message.author.bot) return;` Очевидно, что у объекта `Discord.Message` нету свойства `author`. Для уверенности смотрим в [документацию](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) и видим - действительно нету.

Comment: @Yaant Можете помочь с решением?

Comment: Ну, очевидное (но не обязательно правильное) решение - убрать эту строку. Вообще, Вам должно быть виднее, зачем эта строчка там потребовалась.